# Javascript Facetted Object representions

Tags: javascript, object

I often find myself using 1 big Data Object to combine all information which is useful to have globally available.

```
var globalAppData = {
  member1: x,
  member2: y,
  member_array: [...],
  ...
}
```

Now when the app is growing bigger it becomes a bit tedious to handle.

Another problem is that, when I try to structure it in the way of separating data to

```
var globalAppData = {
  process1relatedMembers: {...},
  process2relatedMembers: {...},
  ...    
}
```

The overhead of making up the structure is unnecessary high, and it cannot create a nicest fit as several members are usually related to multiple processes. That's why the've become part of a global state object in the first place.^^

So I was asking myself if there is any possibility to create faceted Objects like

```
var globalProcess1Data = {
  member1: x,
  member_array: [...]
}

var globalProcess2Data = {
  member1: x,
  member2: y
}
```

where member1 is the exactly same member in both objects.
Like a convenience mask on the globalState object when implementing a certain part of the app.
I did not find something like that yet and I'm assume that such constructs do not exist in JS.

Has anyone an Idea how to create such convenience?

Comment: Dunno, give each object a `sharedData` property that points to the same object from multiple processes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So I was asking myself if there is any possibility to create faceted Objects...where `member1` is the exactly same member in both objects. Like a convenience mask on the `globalState` object when implementing a certain part of the app.

I would lean toward being more modular and/or using nested structures, but without more context for what you ultimately want to achieve it's hard to say for sure.

It **is** possible to do specifically you've asked, using getters and setters:

```
var globalProcess1Data = {
  get member1() {
    return globalAppData.member1;
  },
  set member1(value) {
    globalAppData.member1 = value;
  }
};
```

Live Example:

```js
var globalAppData = {
  member1: null,
  member2: "foo",
  member_array: [/*...*/]
};
var globalProcess1Data = {
  get member1() {
    return globalAppData.member1;
  },
  set member1(value) {
    globalAppData.member1 = value;
  }
};
var globalProcess2Data = {
  get member1() {
    return globalAppData.member1;
  },
  set member1(value) {
    globalAppData.member1 = value;
  },
  get member2() {
    return globalAppData.member2;
  },
  set member2(value) {
    globalAppData.member2 = value;
  }
};
console.log("member1:");
console.log("[before] globalAppData.member1", globalAppData.member1);
console.log("[before] globalProcess1Data.member1", globalProcess1Data.member1);
console.log("[before] globalProcess2Data.member1", globalProcess2Data.member1);
console.log("Setting globalProcess1Data.member1...");
globalProcess1Data.member1 = 42;
console.log("[after]  globalAppData.member1", globalAppData.member1);
console.log("[after]  globalProcess1Data.member1", globalProcess1Data.member1);
console.log("[after]  globalProcess2Data.member1", globalProcess2Data.member1);
console.log("member2:");
console.log("[before] globalAppData.member2", globalAppData.member2);
console.log("[before] globalProcess2Data.member2", globalProcess2Data.member2);
console.log("Setting globalProcess2Data.member2...");
globalProcess2Data.member2 = "bar";
console.log("[after]  globalAppData.member2", globalAppData.member2);
console.log("[after]  globalProcess2Data.member2", globalProcess2Data.member2);
```

Comment: hahaha yhea, somehow I did not think about that^^ In a way it is weird and is not too little to type, but it perfectly does it's job

Comment: For being more modular - in the end it should be exactly that, But to me it appears that having functionality separated from the AppState/globalData helps alot. So the structure can be very clear and specific. To me it is an unsolvable problem to know in beforehand where data will eventually be used.